# gnuplot - Increase size of point only in legend/key

Tags: gnuplot

I have a graph that looks like this:

[image]

I want to increase the size of the points in the legend (is it legend or key?) but without increasing the size of the points in the plot.
It's explained better in the picture. Can this be achieved?

Comment: I wish those were free-hand red circles (FHRC as they're know on meta) ... but your image with associated text conveys very clearly what your problem is and what you're looking for.  Nice question.  (+1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First plot nothing with increased symbol size, then plot the data without the key.

```
gnuplot> plot 1/0 ls 7 lw 6 with points t "0.0", "yourdata" ls 7 notitle
```

Use the same point style for both of the plots, and rename the first plot key as you wish.

Comment: I was looking for something more like a `gnuplot` option rather than a hack, but I have to admit this solution works rather well. Thank you my friend.

Comment: This is a very useful hack to keep around (one which I've used in many of my answers here).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using filled circles (`pt 7`) you may want to adopt this improvement of the Jari's answer which looks better as the points in the key are less fatty and more elegant:

```
plo 1/0 w p lc 1 pt 1 lw 3 ps 3 t "Data 1", "data1.dat" lc 1 pt 1 notitle,\
    1/0 w p lc 3 pt 2 lw 3 ps 3 t "Data 2", "data2.dat" lc 3 pt 2 notitle
```

Comment: You should mention *why* this is supposed to look better. With the point style to OP used it doesn't matter if you use `lw` or `ps`. Only in your case with crosses it does.

Comment: @Christoph "crosses" are called points in gnuplot and they are used in the accepted answer as well as in mine, maybe you were referring to dots? In this case yes, there should be no difference.

Comment: No, by "crosses" I mean the point type which you get with `pt 1`, which is not what the OP uses. He uses `pt 7` which are dots :)

Comment: @Christoph thanks for the note, I improved the answer!